# Confusion about LSTM network with multiple LSTM units

Tags: lstm, stacked-lstm

An LSTM layer can have multiple LSTM units ( LSTM memory cells each with input/update, output, and forget gates). In this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24909/the-model-of-lstm-with-more-than-one-unit), we have 2 LSTM layers each with two cells, and according to the answer, the correct diagram is the last diagram in the question, where the 2 cells in each layer work independently with no crosstalk ( connections between them). This confuses me, because if we, for example, consider the forget gate, here is the equation that governs the forget gate:

[image]

According to my understanding, `ht-1` is a vector of size `M, where` M`is the number of LSTM units. This means that for a given LSTM unit at a given timestep`t`, we need the hidden state values of the previous timestep` t-1` from all of the LSTM units in this layer, and therefore, the LSTM units in a given hidden layer work dependently, and consequently, there should be connections between the LSTM units in the same LSTM Layer. Is that correct?